# iPhone application crashes in didDeselectItemAtIndexPath of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview

I have implemented `UICollectionView` in my application and when I am deselecting image from `UICollectionView` then I am removing that `UIImage` from `NSMutableArray`. Now my problem is,if images are more than two and I am deselecting that images then my application is crashes.

and getting error is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Here is my code  below

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
        didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [selectedImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

I am getting `indexPath` which is beyond to that array.

Comment: and what are doing on didSelect ?

Answer (score 0):

`IndexPath` does not necessarily have a row property, so that might be nil. If it is nil, you would see a crash

Answer (score 0):

check the array count is greater than indexPath.row property and then delete or check if the array element exist for that index, if yes then delete the element

```
if(selectedImageArray[indexPath.row] != nil) {
   [selectedImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Indexpath.row` will return you index of your actual array not selected array index.
So you have to find same element in `SelectedArray` then also you are able to remove that image from selected array.

For Example

Actual Array objects

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

From that you have selected object

`[1,5,7]`

so objects `[1,5,7]` will be in selected states and in `SelectedArray` also.

when you select object `7` at that time `Indexpath.row` will return you `6`

And you are directly removing index `6` from `SelectedArray` which is not available so you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use indexPath.item.
This is normaly used in a collectionView. 
IndexPath.row is used for TableView.

Anyways, put a if condition around it to check if this index is existing.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line of code to handle a check:

```
if ([indexPath.row] < [selectedImagesArray count]) {

    [selectedImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```